# Django Model Filter

Tags: database, django, model, typeerror

I've spent the last few hours looking at Django Docs and similar questions on here but I'm still unclear on how to tackle the problem...

In essense I want to access the list of email addresses relevent to a certain group, so I can send an email to these customers who are part of this group (named group_one, group_two etc)

```
class Group(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
  mailing_list = models.ManyToManyField("Customer", null=True)  

class Customer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
```

I've tried

```
group_mail_list = Group.objects.filter(name=group_two)
```

And this returns an Query Object for group_two but when I try to do a __contains filter I get a error:

```
TypeError: Related Field has invalid lookup: contains
```

Anyone help me out? Not sure if it's because it's a many-to-many relationship perhaps?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: group_mail_list = Group.objects.filter(name='group_two')

Comment: You didn't provide code for the __contains bit. Only for the other example that is working

Comment: that returns an empty list. So is that looking at the mailing_list field in Group object, then the name in the Customer? The name in the Customer object is the Customers name, not the Group name they 'belong' to. I want to drag all the email addresses who are part of mailing_list group two. Hopefully that clarified it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you really want is `Customer`s, then. It seems counter-intuitive on the surface, because you're wanting emails for a `Group`, but that field is on `Customer` not `Group`:

```
Customer.objects.filter(group__name='group_two').values_list('email')
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you I wouldn't have thought of it like that. One more question though if I may - the list returned is like [(u'aname@domain.com',)]. Is there a simple way to eradicate the unicode bit? I assume thats what the u is?

Comment: The `u` is not part of the string. It's just a signal that the string is unicode. Every string Django stores in the database is unicode. Unicode is good -- your want that. It won't actually appear with a `u` in the TO field of the email or anything like that, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: Okay thank you very much would have been stuck on this for days without your help